# Sidebar - react-admin - css class

Tags: css, reactjs, react-admin

I am sure that someone can help me, and I understand that it is not the right place to ask how to do it. But maybe it's a bug: it turns out that I'm trying to put a green border to the sidebar, in the way I indicate in the photo. but I can't find the way, I can't find the css class that I need to edit to achieve it. any help please?

For example
[Sidebar border what I wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZAGI.jpg)

I want to add the green border as indicated in the image. I have tried as the documentation says, but it does not work:

```
import { Sidebar, Layout } from 'react-admin';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useSidebarStyles = makeStyles({
    drawerPaper: {
        borderBootom: "15px solid #006a3c",
    },
});

const MySidebar = props => {
    const classes = useSidebarStyles();
    return (
        <Sidebar classes={classes} {...props} />
    );
};

const MyLayout = props => <Layout {...props} sidebar={MySidebar} />
export default MySidebar;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a typo in the property name, it should be: `borderBottom`

Actually you need to implement your menu component by adding the following style:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#menu

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  menu: {
    borderBottom: "15px solid #006a3c",
  },
})          

const Menu = ({ onMenuClick, logout }) => {
    const isXSmall = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down('xs'));
    const open = useSelector(state => state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen);
    const resources = useSelector(getResources);

    const classes = useStyles()   
    return (
        <div className={classes.menu}>
        ...
        </div>
    );
}
```